# Memory efficient way to store strings

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures

Assume I have millions strings. Each string has an int value. I want to retrieve this value by  input string but I don't want to store all this strings because they take a lot of space. I can't use hash table because of it need to store all or at least many strings in memory. So what is good data structure for my case (I don't need to add or delete any strings, I am already have prepared data and read is only allowed operation)

Comment: What programming language? Also, are there many identical strings?

Comment: @jdv-Jan de Vaan  No all strings are unique. I donnt think that my question language specific but i prefer c#.

Comment: It's unclear what you need to do. Do you just need to extract those numbers and save to another file? Or do you need to perform some calculations with them? Is it OK if the input order isn't preserved?

Comment: @Alexey Frunze i need to extract this values and do some calculations with them. "input order isn't preserved" - what do you mean?

Comment: I mean, say, your input is 4,3,2,1 but you output it as 1*2,2*2,3*2,4*2 (multiplied by 2 but in reverse order). If you need to add all numbers up or multiply them together or XOR, the order won't matter either. Depending on what you need to do, you may or may not be able to reorder the input to your advantage.

Comment: @Alexey Frunze Ok. I undestand. Order is important.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to prevent storing common substrings..

Comment: @larsmans Heh! I've though about something like this for maximizing the efficiency of a very large regex pattern, though now I wonder if this is done automatically when a regex string is parsed.  Nice to know what it's called.

Comment: a hashtable is not a memory efficient way of storing strings, though

Comment: @Neir0 It's going to be speed or size; pick one.

Comment: @Nolo: Tries cannot represent all regular expressions, you need [NFAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton) or [DFAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) for that. Most RE toolkits will actually compile REs to FAs under the hood.

Answer (score 3):

If you can can pre-process the word list take a look at perfect hashes, like [CMPH](http://cmph.sourceforge.net/). ( [gperf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) is another, but seems optimized for smaller data sets. )

From the CMPH docs:

> A perfect hash function maps a static set of n keys into a set of m integer numbers without collisions, where m is greater than or equal to n. If m is equal to n, the function is called minimal.

...

> The CMPH Library encapsulates the newest and more efficient algorithms in an easy-to-use, production-quality, fast API. The library was designed to work with big entries that cannot fit in the main memory. It has been used successfully for constructing minimal perfect hash functions for sets with more than 100 million of keys, ...

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the [Judy tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judy_array), which is designed to be both fast and compact, and has a version designed for string keys.  Its implementation is available on [sourceforge](http://judy.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Your reason to not use a hash table doesn't sound valid based on the limited information in your question currently.  It's fairly efficient if implemented well.  It can also have the advantage of not wasting memory storing duplicate strings if that is acceptable for your needs, further reducing memory consumption if duplicate strings are possible.

You could conceivably also store a compressed form of each string in the hash table if you were creative about how you do lookups.  How long are the strings typically?

Comment: Average length is 10 letters. At least i can do not store strings with one item buckets of my hashtable. So i think there are exists way to inprove this approach.